# Transfer data over SSH directly in Truecrypt volume

Tags: ssh, sftp, file-transfer, truecrypt

my problem is this: I have to transfer data from my computer to a remote system that doesn't have an encrypted partition.

Because I don't want that the transferred data can be retrieved by forensic tools (and I can't set up an encrypted partition at moment) I thought:

- Mount the Truecrypt volume with SSH
- With SFTP transfer data directly in the mounted volume
- Unmount the volume

Is this correct or is it dangerous?

Comment: Why do not create small volume and transfer it?

Comment: Yeah I did like that sometimes but I have to create one volume for each trasferiment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to work directly on the files on your computer, without copying them to the machine you're working on.

```
mkdir ~/net/my-computer
sshfs your-computer: ~/net/my-computer
gedit ~/net/my-computer/my-secret-file.txt
fusermount -u ~/net/my-computer
```

Traces from your data may still end up on the disk via swap or temporary files. You can't avoid this without having root privileges on the computer you're working on.

Of course this only protects against someone who steals the disk after you've been working on that machine. If you do anything on that machine, you need to trust its administrators, since they can siphon see all the data on their machine whenever they please.

Comment: Ok, so if I i'm not wrong I have to mount the encrypted volume on the remote computer and then `sshfs your-computer: ~/net/my-computer`. In other words with SSHFS I don't have to sftp every file but in any case I have to use Truecrypt on the server for security, right?

Comment: You have to use Truecrypt on the server if you're worried about someone stealing the server's hard disk.

Comment: Yeah this is one of my worries. Nevertheless if I'm not wrong I know that the only effective solution is a whole encrypted system because opening Truecrypt volume's files may cause lack of information such as files in /tmp, thumbnails...Do you agree?

Comment: @siv-lab You can avoid most local files by setting `HOME` and `TMPDIR` to point under the SSHFS filesystem, but you can't avoid local swap.